# Dell PowerEdge R610 PERC H700 moving hard disks

Tags: hardware-raid

Current config

Bay.   H700 config

0 & 1    VHD 0 raid 1. Windows D:

2&3&4.   VHD 1 raid 5. Windows E:

5        VHD 2         Windows C:

H700 Boot = VHD 2

If I "SLIDE ALONG" drives by removing bay5, then move 0,1,2,3,4 into 1,2,3,4,5, then insert old bay5 into bay 0, then make changes to h700 to import foreign configs and set boot to  VHD0, will Windows still see D: and E: as they are now without losing data?.

i.e.

0=C: bootable

1&2=D:

3&4&5=E:

Windows Hyper-V 2019